# Elegant/efficient way to have objects survive their scope

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm working with an API that has the form:

```
void setup() { 
  //.. 
}
void render() {
  //.. 
}
void clean_up() {
 //..
}
```

I'm trying to figure what is the most elegant, thread-safe and efficient way to have a persistent class `C` consume instances of class `B` that internally refer to memory demanding instances of class `A`. What I am currently doing is along these lines:

```
C global_c_obj;

void setup() { 
  auto b_obj {std::make_shared<B>()}; // b_obj is parametrised in the actual code
  global_c_obj.push_back(b_obj); // so that b_obj will survive this scope
}

void render() {
  // every several cycles func() is called in a new thread 
  auto results = global_c_obj.get_results(); 
  // do work with results
}

void func() {
  auto new_b_obj {std::make_shared<B>()}; // new object with new parameters
  global_c_obj.push_back(new_b_obj); 
}
```

With class `B` having the form:

```
class B {
private: 
  std::shared_ptr<A> memory_intensive_obj;
  // .. 
public:
  // ... 
};
```

There two things I don't like in this approach but I can't think of a better way at the moment:

1. The object of type `C` is a global one, and I'd rather not use globals at all
2. `C`'s pubic interface is made so as to expect `std::shared_ptr<B>` as arguments, while I'd much rather prefer an interface expecting `B*` or `const B&` so that I could use the same interface in different contexts and with different APIs.

As for point 2. above, and since `B` already holds a `std::shared_ptr<A>` so that it is not particularly large as an object, I could simply pass `B` by value to `C`. But `B` is still larger than `std::shared_ptr<B>` and I think that it'd be more expensive to copy-construct rather than used a `std::shared_ptr`.

Any other tactics around such an architecture?

Comment: If you can change `setup`, `render` and `clean_up` you should pass the object to those functions. If they have no arguments and you cannot change them then you have to use global state.

Comment: what is that API? It looks a little odd that the functions take no arguments.

Comment: Things you may also want to consider: what happens if setup() is called (by mistake) twice? A common safety mechanism for this init(once)-step(many)-pattern is to, instead of a global C, have a global std::optional<C>, and check for it's existence/non-existence in setup(). Optionally firing a (debug) assert if setup() ever takes the "I already exist" branch, to avoid bug-hiding, whilst still having a mechanisms that can facilitate testing without having have separate test binaries for each tests (lifetime of globals ...).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, no I can't change the API - it's for an embedded device and it does accept some certain arguments indeed that I have I left out for the sake of simplicity. But these are all callback functions so that I can't change them to pass my own arguments - at least not without having to redesign the entire API.

Comment: these callback funtions are a potenial way to get information in and out from those functions.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number not really. The code calling them is hidden deep into the (precompiled) library; clients are neither supposed nor expected to mess with it. Clients are only supposed to use the API as is; the arguments exposed are just handlers to hardware devices and system parameters.